# Подключение службы доставки S.F.Express

Tags: php

Всем привет! Ребят, кто-нибудь сталкивался со службой доставки S.F.Express? 
Очень срочная задачка на проекте!!! Пишу сайт на Laravel. 
Собственно вопрос, как подключить эту службу у себя на сайте. Каким образом создать заявку на доставку, получить стоимость доставки? 
https://open.sf-express.com/index.html

Comment: По вашей ссылке есть информация по API

Comment: Да. Вот смотрю её и изучаю. Но непонятно как получить стоимость доставки например?  Ты работал с этим?